# Probability of getting heads twice in a row vs. The same number twice when rolling a dice

Tags: probability, dice

Can someone explain to me that when calculating the odds of flipping a coin twice and it landing heads both times, the formula is $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12$ or $0.5 \times 0.5$ for a result of $0.25$ but when calculating the odds of rolling a dice and it landing on the same number twice it's not $\frac 16 \cdot \frac 16$ or $0.166 \times 0.166$ for a result of $0.027$? I know the answer for the dice is $1/6$ but I'm just confused as to why you can't use the same formula to figure out both.

Comment: Why you think that it is not $\frac 16 \cdot \frac 1 6$ for same number for dice?

Comment: It **is** the same formula, $p^2$, only the value of $p$ is different.

Comment: It depends if you care about the the "value" of the flip / role. The probability for two "heads" is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$, and so is two "tails". But if you don't care if it's two heads OR two tails, then it's just $\frac{1}{2}$. This applies analogously to dice.

Comment: To follow onto @Graviton's comment: The probability for double $1$s is $1/6 \times 1/6 = 1/36$. So is the probability for double $2$s, double $3$s, etc. But the probability that you get a double at all is just $1/6$.

Comment: Actually, I thought of a good thought experiment to demonstrate this subtlety. Imagine rolling an unlabeled die (blank on all sides). Now roll it. Mark whatever side it lands on, and roll it again. What's the probability you land on the side with the same mark the second time? Should just be $1/n$, right? Now that you have a marked die, roll it two more times. Then what is the probability it lands on the side with the mark twice in a row? $1/n \times 1/n$.

Comment: @Graviton thank you, that makes sense now. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

What's important is how many (equally likely) events there are and what events fulfill the desired outcome. For tossing a coin 2 times there are 4 possible outcomes (respecting the order) and only one event is favourable (heads, heads). Hence the probability is $1/4$. For the dice, there are $6 \times 6 = 36$ possible outcomes (respecting the order) and 6 of them fulfil the desired result (that's $(1, 1), (2, 2), \ldots, (6, 6)$). Hence the probability is $6/36 = 1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze why the first probability is $0.5\times 0.5$:
**What is the probability that you get a head on the first coin?** That's $\color{blue}{0.5}$. What is the probability that you get a head on the second coin? Again, it's $\color{blue}{0.5}$, so multiply both to get the final probability.

---

Let's analyze why the second probability is $1/6$:
Using the same logic, **what is the probability you get a -- *number* on the dice?** Of course, it's $\color{green}{1}$, because you are sure to get *some* number. Let's call whatever number appeared on the first dice as $x$. What is the probability that $x$ appears on the second dice? It's $\color{green}{1/6}$. Now, multiply both of them to get the required probability.

---

If you don't get it from the boldfaced text: The difference is that for the dice case, you don't have any fixed number. For the coin case, you were given that you want **heads** on *both* coins. But in the dice case, you want *any number* on the first dice, and the first number on the second dice. 
Say you were given the question:

> You roll $2$ dice, what is the probability that you get $\mathbf 5$ on both the dice?

Here, the answer should be $\frac 16 \times \frac 16$.